# Android app crashes when it reaches the cursor

Tags: android, cursor, crash

I've written some code to get contacts I've stored in a SQLite Database. But when the code reaches the cursor statement, the app suddenly crashes.

Here's the code I've written so far:

```
public class CustomContactsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listCustomContactsList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_contacts);
        listCustomContactsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custom_contacts);
        PopulateList();
    }

    //Insert selected contacts in to the SQLite database
    public void InsertContact(String contactId, String contactName, String[] contactNo) {
        int index = 0;
        String concatContactNo = "";
        BuzzDBHandler dbHandler = new BuzzDBHandler(this);
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();

        if (contactNo.length > 1) {
            for(int i = 0; i<contactNo.length; i++) {
                concatContactNo += contactNo[i].toString() + "#";
            }
        }
        String sql =
                "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO " + BuzzDBSchema.CustomContacts.TABLE_NAME +
                "( " + BuzzDBSchema.CustomContacts.COL_CONTACT_ID + ", " + BuzzDBSchema.CustomContacts.COL_CONTACT_NAME + ", " + BuzzDBSchema.CustomContacts.COL_CONTACT_NO+ " )" +
                "VALUES(" + contactId+ ", " +contactName+ ", " + concatContactNo+ ")";
        database.execSQL(sql);
    }

    private void PopulateList() {
        BuzzDBHandler buzzDBHandler = new BuzzDBHandler(this);
        SQLiteDatabase buzzDB = buzzDBHandler.getReadableDatabase();
        List<String> listCustomContacts = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] selectedColums = {
            BuzzDBSchema.CustomContacts.COL_CONTACT_ID,
            BuzzDBSchema.CustomContacts.COL_CONTACT_NAME,
            BuzzDBSchema.CustomContacts.COL_CONTACT_NO
        };

        Cursor getCustomContacts = buzzDB.query(true, BuzzDBSchema.CustomContacts.TABLE_NAME, selectedColums, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (getCustomContacts.getCount() == 0) {
            dlgWarning();
        } else {
            while (getCustomContacts.moveToNext()) {
                String contactId = getCustomContacts.getString(getCustomContacts.getColumnIndex(BuzzDBSchema.CustomContacts.COL_CONTACT_ID));
                String contactName = getCustomContacts.getString(getCustomContacts.getColumnIndex(BuzzDBSchema.CustomContacts.COL_CONTACT_NAME));
                String contactNo = getCustomContacts.getString(getCustomContacts.getColumnIndex(BuzzDBSchema.CustomContacts.COL_CONTACT_NO));
            }
            getCustomContacts.close();
            ArrayAdapter<String> simpleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listCustomContacts);
            listCustomContactsList.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
        }
    }

    private void dlgWarning() {
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (which) {
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        break;
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
    }    
}
```

The error occurs in my `PopulateList` method on the statement where I perform the query, expecting to receive a cursor:

```
Cursor getCustomContacts = buzzDB.query(true, BuzzDBSchema.CustomContacts.TABLE_NAME, selectedColums, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: can you print the sql statement as it comes out from sticking everything together?

Comment: Replace the whole " buzzDB.query(....null );"  with this 
" buzzDB.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " + BuzzDBSchema.CustomContacts.TABLE_NAME, null,null); " see if this works. Also provide logs if you want further help.

Comment: @Yahodha - I noticed that you don't have single quotes around your contactName (e.g. `VALUES (..., John Smith, ...)` instead of `VALUES (..., 'John Smith', ...)`, so you're probably getting a SQL syntax error. But to be sure, we need to see the error message you're getting. It would also be good to see the final SQL query in your `sql` variable.

Comment: I actually found the reason for my crashing app.

When I added the CustomContacts table to my DB I already had another table in the DB. But after adding the new table I forgot to change the version number in the constructor.

This caused the table to not get properly deployed and therefore my app got crashed when it reached the cursor statement which tried to fetch all the records in the CustomContacts table.

When I increased the version number the problem got fixed.

Thank you so much for the help @ScottSmith udit7395 Juan and Srini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code.

```
if(resultSet != null)
            {
                resultSet.moveToFirst();
                while (!resultSet.isAfterLast()){

                    resultSet.moveToNext();
                }
            }
```